# control swfLoader and sound content in flex

Tags: apache-flex

i am doing a project
and i am loading .swf files in a FLEX 3 SWFLoader.

i made a HSlider as a seeker to control the .swf file (forward and backword);
BUT...
if the swf file has sound and i drag the seeker forward or back word the sound does not effect

**i want to control the sound as i control the swf file**

**note**:: the sound is in the .swf file not loaded

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sound in your swf is probably set to Event, change that to Stream and it will keep in sync with the timeline.